# Cisco Nexus N9K-C92160YC-X kernel panicking at bootup and stuck in endless powercycle

Tags: cisco, switch, cisco-nexus, firmware

I believe I have a bad Cisco Nexus N9K-C92160YC-X.

I received this switch on loan from a customer with a blank configuration.  I've recently learned that its warranty is expired and it's not covered under any service contract.

It booted up successfully the first time I powered it on.  I gave it an interface VLAN 1 IP address and decided I wanted to update its firmware and so I uploaded the nxos.9.3.3.bin firmware to the bootflash and ran the "show install all impact" command to verify that it would be a successful installation.  Everything came back good in the report.

I also applied the following commands:

> diagnostic monitor interval module 1 test PrimaryBootROM hour 23 min
>   59 sec 59
>
> diagnostic monitor interval module 1 test SecondaryBootROM hour 23 min
>   59 sec 59

These were in order to avoid the potential issues outlined in Cisco bug CSCvk30831.  Details regarding this bug can be found here: https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/field-notices/703/fn70320.html

We've run into this bug with several other 9Ks and so I wanted to avoid that problem before I upgraded.

I never actually ran the install.  I shut the switch down for the weekend with plans to run the install on Monday.  On Monday I powered it on and now it won't boot.  The switch is now stuck in a constant powercycle loop.  During bootup I can see it kernel panicking and it appears to be due to a memory error.

Here's the output to the boot sequence:

```
CISCO SWITCH Ver7.59
Device detected on 0:6:0 after 0 msecs
Device detected on 0:1:2 after 0 msecs
Device detected on 0:1:1 after 0 msecs
Device detected on 0:1:0 after 0 msecs
MCFrequency 1333Mhz
Adjusting Clock synthesizer
CLK AFT: 0: ff
CLK AFT: 1: 9e
CLK AFT: 2: 3f
CLK AFT: 3: 75
CLK AFT: 4: 3
CLK AFT: 5: 7
CLK AFT: 6: 13
CLK AFT: 7: 1
CLK AFT: 8: a
CLK AFT: 9: 46
Relocated to memory
Time: 6/1/2020 14:56:17
Pre-Reserving Memory Bar of size 8000000 for root-port B0|D1C|F0 7ffffff 4
Detected CISCO IOFPGA
MIFPGA Present
Code Signing Results: 0x0
Using Upgrade FPGA
Checking and setting PSU fan directions
Booting from Primary Bios
FPGA Revison : 0x17
FPGA ID : 0x1505787
FPGA Date : 0x20161121
Power Debug Register: 0x0
Reset Cause Register: 0x80000000
Boot Ctrl Register : 0xe0ff
FPGA Update Status : 0x20
Detected CISCO MIFPGA
FPGA Update Status : 0x20
Version 2.16.1240. Copyright (C) 2013 American Megatrends, Inc.
Board type 2
IOFPGA @ 0xc8000000
SLOT_ID @ 0xf
Standalone chassis
check_bootmode: grub: Continue grub
Trying to read config file /boot/grub/menu.lst.local from (hd0,4)
Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83

Booting bootflash:/nxos.7.0.3.I3.1.bin ...
Booting bootflash:/nxos.7.0.3.I3.1.bin
Trying diskboot
Filesystem type is ext2fs, partition type 0x83
Image valid


Image Signature verification was Successful.

Boot Time: 6/1/2020 14:56:50
Unprotecting eUSB ...
INIT: version 2.88 booting
Unprotecting eUSB ...
Unsquashing rootfs ...

Loading IGB driver ...
Installing SSE module ... done
Creating the sse device node ... done
Loading I2C driver ...
Installing CCTRL driver for card_type 33 ...
CCTRL driver for card_index 21125 ...
Micron_M500IT_MT
Checking SSD firmware ...
Model Number: Micron_M500IT_MTFDDAT064SBD
Serial Number: MSA2210036X
Firmware Revision: MU01.00

Checking all filesystems.......
Installing default sprom values ...
done.Configuring network ...
Installing LC netdev ...
Installing veobc ...
Installing OBFL driver ...
mounting plog for N9k!
invalid group file entry
delete line 'aaa-db-operator:508:'? No
grpck: no changes
..done Mon Jun 1 14:57:08 UTC 2020
tune2fs 1.42.1 (17-Feb-2012)
Setting reserved blocks percentage to 0% (0 blocks)
Starting portmap daemon...
creating NFS state directory: done
starting 8 nfsd kernel threads: done
starting mountd: done
starting statd: done
Saving image for img-sync ...
Loading system software
Installing local RPMS
Patch Repository Setup completed successfully
dealing with default shell..
file /proc/cmdline found, look for shell
unset shelltype, nothing to do..
user add file found..edit it
Uncompressing system image: Mon Jun 1 14:57:14 UTC 2020
blogger: nothing to do.

..done Mon Jun 1 14:57:14 UTC 2020
Creating /dev/mcelog
Starting mcelog daemon
Overwriting dme stub lib
Replaced dme stub lib
INIT: Entering runlevel: 3
Running S93thirdparty-script...

Populating conf files for hybrid sysmgr ...
Starting hybrid sysmgr ...
[ 33.846766] [1591023444] NMI: PCI system error (SERR) for reason b1 on CPU 0.
[ 33.931884] [1591023444] Memory ERR Staus 0x3
[ 33.983795] [1591023444] pci 0000:00:00.0: Memory ERR Staus 0x3
[ 34.054412] [1591023445] Channel 0 ECC Regs 0x28fa0003 0x200fff1
[ 34.127105] [1591023445] Channel 1 ECC Regs 0x0 0x0
[ 34.186301] [1591023445] ***Channel 0: Un-Correctable mutiple-bit error ***
[ 34.269391] [1591023445] Kernel panic - not syncing: ***Channel 2: Un-Correctable mutiple-bit error ***
[ 34.269393] [1591023445]
[ 34.412682] [1591023445] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/0 Tainted: P O 3.4.43-WR5.0.1.13_standard #1
[ 34.522767] [1591023445] Call Trace:
[ 34.565338] [1591023445] <NMI> [<ffffffff816b13d9>] panic+0xfb/0x23d
[ 34.643228] [1591023445] [<ffffffff8101faad>] host_bridge_memory_errors_reporting+0x47d/0x510
[ 34.746041] [1591023445] [<ffffffff816bb9f0>] ? do_nmi+0x190/0x4e0
[ 34.820812] [1591023445] [<ffffffff816b1585>] ? printk+0x6a/0x83
[ 34.893502] [1591023445] [<ffffffff816bb9f9>] do_nmi+0x199/0x4e0
[ 34.966199] [1591023445] [<ffffffff816bad6c>] end_repeat_nmi+0x1a/0x1e
[ 35.045125] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81305376>] ? intel_idle+0xb6/0xf0
[ 35.121969] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81305376>] ? intel_idle+0xb6/0xf0
[ 35.198816] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81305376>] ? intel_idle+0xb6/0xf0
[ 35.275658] [1591023446] <<EOE>> [<ffffffff81522aaf>] cpuidle_enter_state+0x4f/0xe0
[ 35.369125] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81522c69>] cpuidle_idle_call+0x129/0x220
[ 35.453246] [1591023446] [<ffffffff8100b35f>] cpu_idle+0x7f/0xb0
[ 35.525939] [1591023446] [<ffffffff8168d4c9>] rest_init+0x6d/0x74
[ 35.599671] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81cfac3e>] start_kernel+0x466/0x473
[ 35.678591] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81cfa54f>] ? repair_env_string+0x5a/0x5a
[ 35.762707] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81cfa32a>] x86_64_start_reservations+0x131/0x135
[ 35.855133] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81cfa140>] ? early_idt_handlers+0x140/0x140
[ 35.942368] [1591023446] [<ffffffff81cfa430>] x86_64_start_kernel+0x102/0x111
[ 36.028560] [1591023447] Dumping interrupt statistics
[ 36.088785] [1591023447] CPU0 CPU1 CPU2 CPU3 intrs/last_sec max_intrs/sec
[ 36.210285] [1591023447] 0: 57 0 0 0 57 57 IO-APIC-edge timer
[ 36.341130] [1591023447] 4: 134 0 0 0 10 28 IO-APIC-edge serial
[ 36.473017] [1591023447] 8: 1 0 0 0 0 1 IO-APIC-edge rtc0
[ 36.602823] [1591023447] 9: 0 0 0 0 0 0 IO-APIC-fasteoi acpi
[ 36.732637] [1591023447] 23: 26 0 0 0 25 25 IO-APIC-fasteoi ehci_hcd:usb1
[ 36.871790] [1591023447] 40: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.005753] [1591023447] 41: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.139716] [1591023448] 42: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.273679] [1591023448] 43: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.407644] [1591023448] 44: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.541607] [1591023448] 45: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.675569] [1591023448] 46: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.809533] [1591023448] 47: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge PCIe PME
[ 37.943498] [1591023448] 48: 3488 0 0 0 0 1445 PCI-MSI-edge ahci
[ 38.073310] [1591023449] 58: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge cctrl_tor3_plat_io_isr
[ 38.221809] [1591023449] 59: 0 0 0 0 0 0 PCI-MSI-edge cctrl_tor3_portlib_mi_isr
[ 38.373432] [1591023449] sending NMI to all CPUs:
[ 38.429513] [1591023449] NMI backtrace for cpu 2
[ 38.484550] [1591023449] CPU 2
[ 38.519856] [1591023449] Modules linked in: klm_procfs_init(PO) klm_i2c_stub(O) ata_piix klm_isan_kthread(PO) klm_cmos(PO) klm_ins_igb(O) klm_psdev(O) klm_pfmsvcs(PO) klm_sse(O) klm_tlv(PO) klm_mping(PO) klm_kpss(PO) klm_modlock(O) klm_sdwrap(O) klm_cctrli(PO) klm_if_index(PO) klm_vdc_mgr(O) klm_dc_sprom(O) klm_nvram(O) lc_netdev.mod(O) klm_vdc(O) klm_veobc(O) klm_obfl(O) klm_rwsem(PO) klm_pss(O) klm_aipc(PO) klm_kadb(O) klm_mts(PO) klm_mtsfilter(PO) klm_cctrli_bg(PO) klm_sup_ctrl_mc(PO) klm_rdn_dummy(PO) klm_usd(O) klm_misc(O) klm_gpl(PO) klm_lc_diag_stat(O) klm_ls_notify(PO) klm_fcfwd(PO) klm_fcoe(PO) klm_fc2(PO) klm_cisco_nb(O) klm_kfsmutils(PO) klm_sysmgr-hb(O) klm_sysmgr-hb_lc(O) klm_utaker(O) klm_kgdb(PO)
[ 39.274823] [1591023449]
[ 39.305984] [1591023449] Pid: 10117, comm: sysmgr Tainted: P O 3.4.43-WR5.0.1.13_standard #1 To be filled by O.E.M. To be filled by O.E.M./Aptio CRB
[ 39.475250] [1591023449] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff810392de>] [<ffffffff810392de>] native_flush_tlb_others+0xce/0x110
[ 39.596757] [1591023449] RSP: 0000:ffff880451c3dbe8 EFLAGS: 00000202
[ 39.673607] [1591023449] RAX: 00000000000008d1 RBX: ffff88044094b740 RCX: 0000000000000001
[ 39.772266] [1591023449] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000001 RDI: 0000000000000286
[ 39.870920] [1591023449] RBP: ffff880451c3dc18 R08: ffff88044094b740 R09: 0000000000000000
[ 39.969575] [1591023449] R10: dfed912167b8c580 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000080
[ 40.068231] [1591023449] R13: ffffffff81dcd180 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 000000000a041a7c
[ 40.166886] [1591023449] FS: 0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88047fd00000(0063) knlGS:00000000eca9d940
[ 40.276964] [1591023449] CS: 0010 DS: 002b ES: 002b CR0: 0000000080050033
[ 40.359002] [1591023449] CR2: 000000000a041a7c CR3: 00000004515ae000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
[ 40.457659] [1591023449] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
[ 40.556312] [1591023449] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000ffff0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
[ 40.654968] [1591023449] Process sysmgr (pid: 10117, threadinfo ffff880451c3c000, task ffff88041ab0c3b0)
[ 40.768161] [1591023449] Stack:
[ 40.805542] [1591023449] ffff880451c3dbf8 ffffffff810098e9 ffff88044094b480 ffff88044094b740
[ 40.907309] [1591023449] 000000000a041a7c ffff880453eae3f0 ffff880451c3dc48 ffffffff810394ad
[ 41.009079] [1591023449] ffff88044094b480 ffff880453eae3f0 000000000a041a7c 0000000000000001
[ 41.110849] [1591023449] Call Trace:
[ 41.153438] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810098e9>] ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
[ 41.230286] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810394ad>] flush_tlb_page+0x8d/0xa0
[ 41.309209] [1591023449] [<ffffffff8103805e>] ptep_set_access_flags+0x4e/0x70
[ 41.395404] [1591023449] [<ffffffff8111f54b>] do_wp_page+0x2fb/0x820
[ 41.472250] [1591023449] [<ffffffff811217b6>] handle_pte_fault+0xa86/0xb10
[ 41.555328] [1591023449] [<ffffffff81121bba>] handle_mm_fault+0x1da/0x200
[ 41.637369] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810cde39>] ? trace_clock_local+0x9/0x10
[ 41.720448] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810d44ef>] ? rb_reserve_next_event.isra.33+0x9f/0x300
[ 41.818067] [1591023449] [<ffffffff816be3c3>] do_page_fault+0x353/0x5d0
[ 41.898026] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810639ab>] ? queue_delayed_work+0x2b/0x30
[ 41.983181] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810639cb>] ? schedule_delayed_work+0x1b/0x20
[ 42.071453] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810d8a16>] ? trace_wake_up+0x26/0x30
[ 42.151416] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810da588>] ? trace_current_buffer_unlock_commit+0x48/0x60
[ 42.253185] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810e8884>] ? ftrace_syscall_exit+0xb4/0xd0
[ 42.339379] [1591023449] [<ffffffff8100f172>] ? syscall_trace_leave+0xb2/0x170
[ 42.426611] [1591023449] [<ffffffff811481b9>] ? sys_read+0x59/0x100
[ 42.502419] [1591023449] [<ffffffff816ba9e5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
[ 42.577186] [1591023449] Code: c1 3b ca 00 41 8d b6 cf 00 00 00 49 8d 7d 18 ff 90 d8 00 00 00 41 8b b4 24 18 d1 dc 81 85 f6 74 0e 0f 1f 40 00 f3 90 41 8b 4d 18 <85> c9 75 f6 83 3d 7b 4e ca 00 20 49 c7 84 24 00 d1 dc 81 00 00
[ 42.816027] [1591023449] Call Trace:
[ 42.858614] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810098e9>] ? sched_clock+0x9/0x10
[ 42.935463] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810394ad>] flush_tlb_page+0x8d/0xa0
[ 43.014389] [1591023449] [<ffffffff8103805e>] ptep_set_access_flags+0x4e/0x70
[ 43.100584] [1591023449] [<ffffffff8111f54b>] do_wp_page+0x2fb/0x820
[ 43.177427] [1591023449] [<ffffffff811217b6>] handle_pte_fault+0xa86/0xb10
[ 43.260507] [1591023449] [<ffffffff81121bba>] handle_mm_fault+0x1da/0x200
[ 43.342548] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810cde39>] ? trace_clock_local+0x9/0x10
[ 43.422133] [1591023449] END: PANIC REPORT GENERATED AT 1591023449
[ 43.422139] [1591023449] CCTRL PANIC DUMP
[ 43.422140] [1591023449] =========================
[ 43.422142] [1591023449] WDT last punched at 0
[ 43.422145] [1591023449] REG(0x300) = baadbeef
[ 43.422148] [1591023449] REG(0x304) = baadbeef
[ 43.422149] [1591023449] =========================
[ 43.422152] [1591023449] pstore: Dump l1 0 l2 96741 ToDump 65512 Dumped 0
[ 43.906455] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810d44ef>] ? rb_reserve_next_event.isra.33+0x9f/0x300
[ 44.004069] [1591023449] [<ffffffff816be3c3>] do_page_fault+0x353/0x5d0
[ 44.084027] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810639ab>] ? queue_delayed_work+0x2b/0x30
[ 44.169185] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810639cb>] ? schedule_delayed_work+0x1b/0x20
[ 44.257462] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810d8a16>] ? trace_wake_up+0x26/0x30
[ 44.337424] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810da588>] ? trace_current_buffer_unlock_commit+0x48/0x60
[ 44.439196] [1591023449] [<ffffffff810e8884>] ? ftrace_syscall_exit+0xb4/0xd0
[ 44.525385] [1591023449] [<ffffffff8100f172>] ? syscall_trace_leave+0xb2/0x170
[ 44.612617] [1591023449] [<ffffffff811481b9>] ? sys_read+0x59/0x100
[ 44.688426] [1591023449] [<ffffffff816ba9e5>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
[ 44.763197] [1591023449] NMI backtrace for cpu 3
[ 44.818233] [1591023449] CPU 3
[ 44.853536] [1591023449] Modules linked in: klm_procfs_init(PO) klm_i2c_stub(O) ata_piix klm_isan_kthread(PO) klm_cmos(PO) klm_ins_igb(O) klm_psdev(O)
```

Since the device's warranty is expired and it's not covered under a service contract I don't believe I'm able to open a Cisco TAC support request.  I believe at this point it's up to my own devices to try and fix this thing.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "_its warranty is expired and it's not covered under any service contract._" then "_I uploaded the nxos.9.3.3.bin firmware to the bootflash_" You are not allowed to upgrade the code without a contract that allows it. That is actually against the law. Unfortunately, we cannot help with bad hardware. You need to purchase a service contract, then get Cisco to replace it under the contract.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware that it was against the law.  I didn't know it wasn't under warranty until after I performed those steps above.  I've reached out to the customer and they're working on getting it under contract.  I'll report back when it's back up and running.

Comment: Pop it open and reseat the memory. (or get it under smartnet and get Cisco to fix it.) A memory chip could actually be bad, but in my experience that's very rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get a Cisco TAC request opened.  I really wanted to troubleshoot and fix it with Cisco Support but Cisco determined that the best course of action was to RMA it.

I was able get it to "sorta" bootup from the loader> prompt by uploading an image using tftp.  While in the loader> prompt I issued the "init system" command to reinitialize and reformat the bootflash.  It failed to format the bootflash.  It eventually dropped me into the bash-4.2# prompt and I was able to see using the "parted --list" command that no filesystem was present on the bootflash: partition (apparently bootflash on these devices is really just mapped to the /dev/sda4 partition.)  I believe I could have just manually formatted that partition at this point but I really got worried about potentially voiding any possible support from Cisco.

At any rate, Cisco was very quick about sending me a replacement and now I'm back up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

At this point this sounds like a hardware problem or generally bad Nexus9K device. I'd renew the contract if possible and contact Cisco TAC for a RMA, I doubt there's something that you can do at this point;